# makemigrations - App 'stock_market' could not be found. is it in INSTALLED_APPS?

Tags: python, django

Edit the project/settings.py file again, and change the INSTALLED_APPS setting to include the string 'polls'. So it’ll look like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'stock_market'
]
```

When I run command

```
python manage.py makemigrations stock_market/
```

it gives me that error

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error you are getting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `/` at the end of `stock_market/`

```
python manage.py makemigrations stock_market
```